# Insert 'Text' field data type into MySQL using EJB 3

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, ejb-3.0

```
 private String message = "";
 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }

 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }
```

I am using EJB3 and MySQL 5.1 using Java.
I want to insert paragraphs of texts into MySQL Database using Entity Bean.
But, When I add, MySQL can accept only 255 characters.  It shows me the following error:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'message' at row 1

Currently, field type of message is varchar(255) by default.  Is there anyway to change the field type to "Text" in Entity Bean or increase the limit 255 to 1000?

Comment: varchar of Mysql has a Max length of 255. You'll have to use a 'text' data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the property with `javax.persistence.Lob`:

```
private String message = "";

@Lob
public String getMessage() {
  return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
}
```

You would have to update your schema too (ALTER TABLE...). Hibernate does this automatically for you if you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.